# python3 -m http.server with ssl

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate, http.server

I would like to set up a test server using the http.server library.

To set up a simple test server, we would commonly use the command

```
python3 -m http.server <port>
```

But I have to test, the connection over TLS and therefore need a simple "one-liner", to include a ssl-certificate.

Is there by any chance another flag, I could use to include a dummy self-signed certificate?

Or do I have to write a casual script, generate a certificate using by using openssl etc.?

This said, I know how to generate a certificate and use more "compplicated ways". I am searching for the most lightway version.

Thanks a lot

Comment: [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) can provide a simple TLS file server from the command line.

Comment: thx @larsks, but according to that thread https://caddy.community/t/use-caddy-for-local-https-tls-between-front-end-reverse-proxy-and-lan-hosts/11650 its not as simple as just using a flag ... than writing a bash script using openssl might be also an alternative.

Comment: It really is as simple as just using a flag. See the `caddy file-server` command.

Comment: okay, I'll give it a try. Thanks for mention it anyway.